# how to close a excel file without crashing if error occurs in the below code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, apache-poi

The below code i am trying to execute is corrupting the excel file whenever an exception occurs before closing the `FileInputStream` and `FileOutPutStream`. So i tried keeping `try catch` block and in the `catch` block closed `FileInputStream` and `FileOutPutStream`, still excel is getting crashed.

So i thought something like this if `FileInputStream` is not closed then close in catch block . If `FileOutPutStream` is not closed then close in catch block. But how to achieve this?

or

Is there any better way to handle this situation?

```
public void checkingAccountNumber() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);  


        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\vyerrami\\Desktop\\MA_Conversion_Data.xlsx");


        XSSFWorkbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("DEFERRED");

        int noOfRows=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

        try {

        for(int i=1; i<noOfRows; i++) {
            DataFormatter d = new DataFormatter();
            String cellvalue = d.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(5));

            String firstcellvalue=d.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0));

            if(firstcellvalue.isEmpty()) {
                driver.findElement(quickJump).click();
                driver.findElement(quickJump).sendKeys("AccountSearch");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                driver.findElement(quickJump).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(loading)));

                driver.findElement(accountSearchAccountNumberField).clear();
                driver.findElement(accountSearchAccountNumberField).sendKeys(cellvalue);
                driver.findElement(accountSearchAccountNumberField).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);



                driver.findElement(accountSearchSearchButton).click();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(loading)));


                    if (driver.findElements(By.id("AccountSearch:AccountSearchScreen:AccountSearchResultsLV:0:AccountNumber")).size() > 0) {
                        if (driver.findElement(By.id("AccountSearch:AccountSearchScreen:AccountSearchResultsLV:0:AccountNumber")).getText().contains(cellvalue)) {
                            driver.findElement(By.id("AccountSearch:AccountSearchScreen:AccountSearchResultsLV:0:AccountNumber"))
                                    .click();


                                fis.close();
                                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                                        "C:\\Users\\vyerrami\\Desktop\\MA_Conversion_Data.xlsx");

                                if(driver.findElements(policyFilePolicyNumber).size()>0) {

                                    sheet.getRow(i).createCell(0)
                                            .setCellValue(driver.findElement(policyFilePolicyNumber).getText());                            


                                    sheet.getRow(i).createCell(1)
                                            .setCellValue(driver.findElement(policyFileEffectiveDate).getText());
                                    wb.write(out);
                                    out.close();
                                }
                                else {
                                    sheet.getRow(i).createCell(0)
                                    .setCellValue("Policy Number is not present");  
                                    wb.write(out);
                                    out.close();
                                }


                        }

                        }

                    else {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                                "C:\\Users\\vyerrami\\Desktop\\MA_Conversion_Data.xlsx");
                        sheet.getRow(i).createCell(0)
                        .setCellValue("Account Number is not present");
                        wb.write(out);
                        out.close();

                    }

            }


        }
        }


    catch(Exception e)
    {

    //i want to write the code if fis is not closed then i have to close 
    //i want to write the code is out is not closed then i have to close

    }

}
```

EDIT CODE WHICH IS WORKING IS BELOW:

```
FileInputStream fis=null;
        FileOutputStream out1=null;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook= null;
        XSSFSheet sheet = null;

try {   
            fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\vyerrami\\Desktop\\VINS.xlsx");
            out1 = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\vyerrami\\Desktop\\VINS.xlsx");
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sheet = workbook.getSheet("VINS");

            int noOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                driver.findElement(createVehicleButton).click();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(loading)));

                driver.findElement(EnterVinNumber).clear();

                driver.findElement(EnterVinNumber).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());               
                driver.findElement(EnterVinNumber).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(loading)));

                driver.findElement(vehicleInquiryButton).click();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(loading)));


                System.out.println(driver
                        .findElement(By.xpath(
                                "//*[@id='VehicleInquiryReportPopup:2-body']/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div"))
                        .getText());
                System.out.println(driver
                        .findElement(By.xpath(
                                "//*[@id='VehicleInquiryReportPopup:2-body']/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/div"))
                        .getText());


                if (driver
                        .findElement(By.xpath(
                                "//*[@id='VehicleInquiryReportPopup:2-body']/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div"))
                        .getText().equalsIgnoreCase("null null")
                        || !driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                                "//*[@id='VehicleInquiryReportPopup:2-body']/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/div"))
                                .getText().equalsIgnoreCase("null null") && (sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue().isEmpty())) {
                    fis.close();
                    sheet.getRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue("Not Leased");
                    workbook.write(out1);
                    out1.close();
                    workbook.close();

                }

                else {
                    fis.close();
                    sheet.getRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue("Leased");
                    workbook.write(out1);
                    out1.close();
                    workbook.close();
                }

                driver.findElement(By.id("VehicleInquiryReportPopup:__crumb__")).click();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(loading)));

                driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                        "//*[@id='SubmissionWizard:LOBWizardStepGroup:LineWizardStepSet:PAVehiclesScreen:PAVehiclesPanelSet:VehiclesListDetailPanel:VehiclesLV-body']/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/img"))
                        .click();
                driver.findElement(By.id(
                        "SubmissionWizard:LOBWizardStepGroup:LineWizardStepSet:PAVehiclesScreen:PAVehiclesPanelSet:VehiclesListDetailPanel_tb:Remove"))
                        .click();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(loading)));

            }




        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(fis!=null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            if(out1!=null) {
                out1.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that you are looking for [try with resource](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources). It's sugar syntax for opening stream in try block and closing it in finally block. This way whatever happens in try block, stream is closed.

In most cases, you should open streams as late as possible and close them as soon as possible. Try to make smaller methods, so it is easier to debug them later.

Comment: Perfect _...open streams as late as possible and close them as soon as possible..._